# Ansible "expect" module with sudo?

Tags: ansible, expect

I want to run an installer script with Ansible. The installer script prompts for a number of responses and requires to be run with root privileges.

Here is the essence of my Ansible task:

```
- expect:
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  command: "installer.bin"
  echo: yes
  responses:
    "Choose the appropriate installation or upgrade option.": "2"
    "Where should the software be installed?": "/opt/newsoftware/"
```

I would have thought this would work, but I get the error

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: become_method"}
```

If I omit "become_method", I get this error instead:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: become"}
```

My Ansible is version 2.1.1.0

Comment: Which version of ansible are you using? Post the out put of: `ansible --version`

Comment: the default for become_method is sudo. So you can omit it.

Comment: Version is ansible 2.1.1.0. 
If I omit "become_method", I get "unsupported parameter for module: become" instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to write the task like:

```
- expect:
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  args:
    command: "installer.bin"
    echo: yes
    responses:
      "Choose the appropriate installation or upgrade option.": "2"
      "Where should the software be installed?": "/opt/newsoftware/"
```

You could omit `become_method`.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me.This still gives me the error `"unsupported parameter for module: become_method"`. If I omit become_method, I get the error `"unsupported parameter for module: args"`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't pay close enough attension to your indenting. You were right of course. My original mistake was to not have `become` at the same indentation level as `expect`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't worry. I am still learning Ansible too. I am glad that I could help.